# How to use the .get() function with a Radio Button

Tags: python, radio-button, tkinter

I am trying to make a basic drawing program with a RadioButton to determine shape of the brush.

```
self.choseo = Radiobutton(text='Circle', variable=shape,indicatoron=0, value=1)
self.choser = Radiobutton(text='Rectangle', variable=shape,indicatoron=0, value=2)
self.chosea = Radiobutton(text='Arc', variable=shape,indicatoron=0, value=3)
```

Which corresponds to:

```
   if shape.get()==3:
      self.display.create_arc( self.x1, self.y1, self.x2,
          self.y2, fill = mycolor, outline= mycolor, tags = "line")
   elif shape.get()==2:
      self.display.create_rectangle( self.x1, self.y1, self.x2,
          self.y2, fill = mycolor, outline= mycolor, tags = "line")
   elif shape.get()==1:
      self.display.create_oval( self.x1, self.y1, self.x2,
          self.y2, fill = mycolor, outline= mycolor, tags = "line")
```

When i run this i get this error:

```
"TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)"
```

How do i make this work?

Comment: What is shape?  Generally .get() accepts an index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't tell what `shape` is, but you should make sure your use an instance of `IntVar`.

Try the following code:

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
shape = IntVar() # ensure you use an instance of IntVar
Radiobutton(text='Circle', variable=shape, indicatoron=0, value=1, master=master).pack()
Radiobutton(text='Rectangle', variable=shape, indicatoron=0, value=2, master=master).pack()
Radiobutton(text='Arc', variable=shape, indicatoron=0, value=3, master=master).pack()
```

and `shape.get()` will work the way you want.